How to make 2 gaps in a curve which can change position independently?
I want to create two gaps in a curve, with the ability to independently control the position and width of each gap.
In the attached Blender file, I’ve come up with a setup using three Trim Curve nodes. The first two Trim Curve nodes are used to create a large gap in the middle, and the third one is meant to ‘fill’ the gap I just created.
The issue with this approach is that when the first gap overlaps or extends beyond the second gap, it no longer works as expected.
Does anyone have a better solution for this?




I don't know how precisely you want to control this, and what your goal is, but you could limit the values with the Clamp node.

My goal is for the user to be able to activate one gap, then activate the other gap later, without needing to adjust the 'position' and 'width' settings of the first one. I considered using a clamp node so that they don't cross each other, but that would make the settings of one gap always dependent on the other (maybe I'm wrong)

The puzzle can be solved if the following criteria are met:
The first curve is given the lower value of as the end point:

Starting point of the second gap.
The starting point of the first gap, or the end point of the second gap, if the starting point of the first gap is greater than the end point of the second gap.

The third curve receives the higher value of as the starting point:

End point of the first gap.
End point of the second gap, or starting point of the first gap, if the starting point of the first gap is greater than the end point of the second gap.

The starting point of the middle curve is either:

The end point of the first gap.
The end point of the second gap, if the start point of the first gap is greater than the start point of the second gap.

The middle curve has as its end point either:

The start point of the second gap.
The starting point of the first gap if the starting point of the first gap is greater than the starting point of the second gap.

Translated into geometry nodes, this could look something like this:

(Blender 4.2.0+)

Haha, wow this is amazing. I'm looking forward to the day I can figure this out by myself. I have to admit I'm not able for the moment. Big thanks again Stephan. A drink is coming your way!
